# does smartfoxserver2x support push?

Tags: smartfoxserver

There is not much documentation, but here is the section about writing server side extensions:

http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/AdvancedTopics/server-side-extensions

And here is the feature list:

http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/Overview/sfs2x-features

There is no mention of push or queues.

There are bingo games out there using smartfox server, and they must be using it to call the balls for example.

Can this be done using SFS2x?  Does it support push notification and ideally queues of items to be pushed to a group of clients?  If so, does anyone have any source code or examples?

The SFS forums are, sadly closed and not open to posting.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a bingo game in sfs2x. I can only give you a guide so I hope it helps. If I understand the question, you want to send commands without a request or event triggering the command.

Create a commands class:
the package path is relative to you src folder.

```
package com.rcras.bingo1;

public class Commands

{
/** User buys bingo cards */
public static final String CMD_BUY_CARDS = "bc";
/** Server sends Bingo */
public static final String CMD_BINGO = "bo";

/** User Calls Bingo */
public static final String CMD_CALL_BINGO = "bingo";

/** Get the time left till next game */
public static final String CMD_GET_TIMER = "get_timer";

/** No bingos left --- Game Over */
public static final String CMD_GAME_OVER= "gaov";

/** Ready to start a game */
public static final String CMD_READY = "ready";

/** Bingo Draw */
public static final String CMD_DRAW = "draw";
/** tell the client app the game is starting */
public static final String CMD_START = "start";
}
```

I have not included all the commands I used. There is no need to set up event or request handlers because the command is sent from server side timer event.

You will have to write a 'bingogame' class and call that class from you extension. My objective was to have a number of rooms that run games concurrently. I tracked the games using ConcurrentHashMap:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import com.rcras.bingo1.Commands;

public class Bingo1 extends SFSExtension {
    List<User> DiamondRoomPlayers;
    Timer timer;
    private  static int min =2;
    private  static int sec = 60;
    /** Current games */
    private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,BingoGame> games = null;


public ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, BingoGame> getGames() {
    return games;
}

public void startDiamondGame()
{
    Zone thisZone = this.getParentZone();
    Room room2 = thisZone.getRoomByName("Diamond");
    BingoGame bingoGame = this.getGames().get(room2.getId());
    if(bingoGame == null || (bingoGame != null && bingoGame.isStarted() == false))
    {
            DiamondRoomPlayers=room2.getUserList();
            ISFSObject DiamondObj = new SFSObject();    
            send(Commands.CMD_START, DiamondObj, DiamondRoomPlayers);
            BingoGame DiamondRoomGame = new BingoGame(this, room2);
            getGames().put(room2.getId(),DiamondRoomGame);
            DiamondRoomGame.setId(room2.getId()) ;
            DiamondRoomGame.init();
    }

}
```

The BingoGame Class has a timer triggering the draws

```
public class BingoGame {
public BingoGame(Bingo1 ext, Room room)
{
    Draw= new int[75];
    setPlayers(room.getUserList());
    //players = room.getUserList();
    thisRoom = room;
    this.extension=ext;
//setters
    this.setFirstBingo(true);
    this.setStarted(false);
    this.setSecondBingo(true);
    this.setFirstPrize(1000);
    this.setSecondPrize(500);
}
public void init()
{
    if(players.size() > 0)
    {
        StartBingoGame();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("NOT ENOUGH PLAYER IN THE" + thisRoom.getName() + " Room!" );
    }
}
private void StartBingoGame()
{
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new BingoDrawTask(),
               0,        //initial delay
               1*3000);  //draw a number every 3 seconds
    setStarted(true); //setter for started variable

}

class BingoDrawTask extends TimerTask {

    private int BingoNum;
    private boolean isThere = true;
    @Override
    public void run() {

        isThere = true;

        Random BingoCall = new Random();
        while( isThere == true)
        {
        BingoNum = BingoCall.nextInt(75) + 1;
        System.out.println("Bingo Draw:" + BingoNum);
        isThere = CheckDrawArray(BingoNum);
        }
        Draw[NunbersCalled]=BingoNum;
        NunbersCalled = NunbersCalled + 1;
        System.out.println(thisRoom.getName() + " Room:    Draw Number: " + NunbersCalled);
//this should never happen but it's there for testing
        if (NunbersCalled == 75)
        {
            System.out.println("STOP!!!" );
            StopBingoGame();
        }
        // Empty obj
        ISFSObject numObj = new SFSObject();
        numObj.putInt("cn", NunbersCalled);
        numObj.putInt("dn", BingoNum);
        numObj.putUtfString("rn", thisRoom.getName());
/*This command 'pushes' the command to a player list named players
        extension.send(Commands.CMD_DRAW, numObj, players);
        System.out.println("Send ----" + BingoNum);

    }
```

on the client side

add an event listener

```
sfs.addEventListener(SFSEvent.EXTENSION_RESPONSE, onExtensionResponse);
```

add the handler

```
private function onExtensionResponse(evt:SFSEvent):void
    {
        var obj:SFSObject = evt.params.params as SFSObject;

        if(evt.params.cmd == "draw")
        {
            //Handle draw - mostly handled by BingoCard class
        }
    }
```

I tried to keep this brief but it didn't happen. I hope I've given you enough code to show you how I achieved a push? in my 'BINGO GAME'.

Answer (score 0):

Give try to our push connected game features [HTML5 sample game walkthrough](https://github.com/Nuggeta/nuggeta-games-samples)

Hope this help.